# Arrays and Files in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

So I've recently switched from Python into learning Java and i'm having trouble getting 2d arrays to work. I managed to get reading from the file working and appending the text in the file into an array. But I only managed to get as far as writing the contents of the file into an array as one item. Being fluent in Python means that I would consider myself to be quite understanding of how constructs work, its just i'm struggling to adjust to what library/method to use in doing this.

This is the contents of the text file I would like to split into an array line by line.

```
    Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65 into [[Mildred Bush],[45],[65],[67],[65]]
    Fred Snooks 23 43 54 23 76               etc.
    Morvern Callar 65 45 34 87 76            etc.
    Colin Powell 34 54 99 67 87
    Tony Blair 67 76 54 22 12
    Peter Gregor 99 99 99 99 99
```

Code without arrays working.

```
    public void Process() {
    String filename;
    filename = "Details.txt";


    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    List<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();


    try{

        fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

        String nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(nextLine);
            nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            nextLine.split(",");
            System.out.print(nextLine);
            alist.add(nextLine);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error reading from file: " + e);
    }
    System.out.print(alist);

}
```

So the way I was going to go about it was by using .split twice, splitting by "\n" then " ". To create a 2d array. But i couldnt get this working and I was wondering if there was a different library/method to use to read each line of a file into a 2d array. I looked into using the ArrayList module(?) with again no success of getting eachline line to split.

Comment: Well, really, you should have an object that wraps the properties, then you'd add that to your `List`.  Parsing your `String` isn't hard, except the delimiter would also split the name, so you'd have to be ware of that ;).  I'd start by exploring what `nextLine.split(" ");` results in

Comment: @MadProgrammer yea, so i already tried using .split with nextLine but i got caught by a nullpointerexception. Hence why ive been stuck

Comment: `while (nextLine != null){` should be `while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){` otherwise you're not updating the value.  `String#split` will split a string by the delimiter into an array.  Perhaps you should provide an example of your attempt

Comment: So I tried again but i keep getting hit by the same exception. The updated try is above

Comment: Since you data seems to be separated by a space, but you seem to be trying to split by a ",", then either the information you've provided is wrong or your using the wrong delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I took you data:

```
Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65
Fred Snooks 23 43 54 23 76
Morvern Callar 65 45 34 87 76
Colin Powell 34 54 99 67 87
Tony Blair 67 76 54 22 12
Peter Gregor 99 99 99 99 99
```

Modified you code like:

```
String filename;
filename = "Details.txt";

List<String[]> alist = new ArrayList<String[]>();

try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

    String nextLine = null;
    while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = nextLine.split(" ");
        String[] elements = new String[parts.length - 1];
        elements[0] = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
        System.arraycopy(parts, 2, elements, 1, elements.length - 1);
        alist.add(elements);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading from file: " + e);
}
for (String[] values : alist) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

and got it to print:

```
[Mildred Bush, 45, 65, 45, 67, 65]
[Fred Snooks, 23, 43, 54, 23, 76]
[Morvern Callar, 65, 45, 34, 87, 76]
[Colin Powell, 34, 54, 99, 67, 87]
[Tony Blair, 67, 76, 54, 22, 12]
[Peter Gregor, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99]
```

As I said earlier, it would be easier to start with a `Object` representation of the data and read the data into it, but that's me.

This example makes a lot of assumptions about the state of the data, so beware

Take a look at [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details about the `try (...) {...} catch {...}` statement I've used